# Doctrine querybuilder TO_DAYS

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is there any equivalent for doctrine of sql query?

```
SELECT something FROM tbl_name
WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(date_col) <= 30;
```

entity has

```
/**
* @var \DateTime
* @ORM\Column(type="datetime",nullable=true)
*/
protected $newStatusData;
```

So, i need to get all records with condition

```
"nowDate - newStatusData =< 30 days"
```

UPDATE

Thanks to Alok , answer was given below

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class QuestRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    function  getNewQuests(){
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT q FROM AppBundle:Quest q WHERE DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE() , q.newStatusData) >= 30');
        $result = $query->getResult();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you're looking for [DATE_DIFF()](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions) DQL function. It calculate the difference in days between given dates.

It accepts two arguments of **date**.

So you can query the data like this,

```
<?php
    $result=$this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("SELECT EN from Bundle:EntityName WHERE DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),EN.newStatusData)>=30")
            ->getResult();
?>
```

**CURRENT_DATE()** returns the current date.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions

Comment: Omg, after 4 months i understood how to use EntityRepositories (facepalm)

i have error when run this

$currentDate = new DateTime();
return  $this->getEntityManager()
->createQuery("SELECT q FROM AppBundle:Quest q WHERE DATE_DIFF(':currentdate',q.newStatusData) >= 30")
->setParameter('currentdate',$currentDate)
->getResult();
Too many parameters: the query defines 0 parameters and you bound 1

Comment: Please accept it as correct answer if it worked for you. Might help future SO users as well.